# How to check if current javascript/typescript object is of type of ObservableArray?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mobx

How to check if current javascript/typescript object is of type of ObservableArray ?

I tried doing `typeof myObject` but it returns me object.

I am using mobx store and one observable field of store has a array property which is resolved as ObservableArray.

Comment: Did you try and use `myObject instanceof ObservableArray` ?

Comment: Yes I tried in console, result is not available 
myObject instanceof ObservableArray: <not available> or 
Uncaught ReferenceError: ObservableArray is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Mobx has exported `isObservableArray` function which will return true or false. Simple as that.

More info and other similar function here: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/api.html#isobservableobject-array-map-and-isboxedobservable